# Сохранение данных в таблицу, используя ORM

Tags: framework, orm, php, kohana

Как новичек вообще во фреймворке я поставил себе задачу сохранить какие-нибудь данные в таблицу, используя ORM, создал таблицу `tests(id,name)`, создал файл test.php в директории model, вот его листинг:

```
class Model_Test extends ORM
{

protected $_table_name = 'tests';

};
```

Далее создал файл apply.php в папке controller, его содержание такое:

```
<?php

class Controller_Apply extends Model_Test{

$test = ORM::factory('tests');

$test->name = "MyName";
$test->save();

};
```

Естественно следующий мой шаг был переход на `mysite.com/apply`, в итоге kohana вернула мне ошибку:

[image]

Что я сделал не так?

Спасибо за ответ, это как метод дей-но будет логичнее использовать, сейчас обернул в функцию свои команды, но теперь возникла другая ошибка: [image]

Answer (score 1):

[@AlexWindHope](/users/3545/alexwindhope) всё верно написал. Почти. В кохане контроллеры нужно наследовать от класса Controller (или Controller_Template). Рабочим будет следующий код при обращении /apply/test:

```
class Controller_Apply extends Controller {
    // тут не должно быть кода, за исключением
    // полей, констант и методов класса
    // т.е. ваш код нужно поместить в какой-то метод
    // например как-то так
    public function action_test() {
      $test = ORM::factory('tests');
      $test->name = "MyName";
      $test->save();
      // code ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам в матчасть по ООП вообще и ООП в PHP непосредственно, неправильно определили класс, не поленюсь распишу:

```
class Controller_Apply extends Model_Test {
    // тут не должно быть кода, за исключением
    // полей, констант и методов класса
    // т.е. ваш код нужно поместить в какой-то метод
    // например как-то так
    public function test() {
      $test = ORM::factory('tests');
      $test->name = "MyName";
      $test->save();
      // code ....
    }
}
```

PS: ИМХО рановато вам в фреймворки лезть, подучите матчасть.

PPS: ORM тут явно не причем =)

Comment: Но я все-таки хочу совершить свой коварный план и добавить запись в таблицу, см. дополнение.

Comment: Вы с английским дружите? Даже если нет, открываете google переводчик, переводите и читаете: метод before не существует. Что не понятного? -_-

Comment: дружу с английским, но перевод мало мне о чем говорит.